# Leaflet - Get feature.properties of a geojson and insert into a new control

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I work on leaflet.

I have on my map many points from a geojson. When a user clicks on a point a pop-up appears with the attributes of the point. I use the following code :

```
var comm= L.geoJson(commandes, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latLng) {
      return new L.Marker(latLng, {
        icon: new myIcon({
          iconUrl: '/dev/css/iconPA.png'
        })
      }).bindPopup("<b><center><FONT color = 999999> La référence de la commande sélectionnée est </b>" + "<b>" + feature.properties.cd_ref_sdeer                       
        );
  }
});
```

I created a new control at the bottom of my map. I want that control gives the attributes of the geojson too. I thought I could use the following snippet and put the "feature.properties.my_attribute" in "this._div.innerHTML" :

```
    var myButton = L.control(
{position: 'bottomleft'}
);
   myButton.onAdd = function (map) {
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-new-control');
    this._div.innerHTML = 'Statistiques générales : <br><br> - Nombre de points lumineux dans la commune : <FONT COLOR = D01ABB> </FONT><br> - Nombre de commandes dans la commune : <FONT COLOR = D01ABB> 12 </FONT> <br> - Nombre de luminaires installés : <FONT COLOR = D01ABB> <?php while($data5 = mysql_fetch_array($result5)) { echo $data5[cnblum]; } ?> </FONT><br>- Total des puissances installées : <FONT COLOR = D01ABB><?php while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) { echo $data[pw]; } ?> Watts </FONT><br>- Nombre de pannes actuellement déclarées : <FONT COLOR = D01ABB><?php while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($result4)) { echo $data2[cetat]; } ?></FONT></li>' ; 
    return this._div;
};

myButton.addTo(map);
```

But I have that error "Uncaught ReferenceError: feature is not defined" and I don't know how to do ...

Have you some ideas ?
Thanks !

Comment: Can you post this on a demo site so we can properly troubleshoot this?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you want to happen? You click on a button at the bottom and it shows...what? How does it know which feature to display attributes from?